# AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer: Cannot append sample buffer: Must start a session (using -AVAssetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:) first'

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, avassetwriter

I'm using [ARVideoKit](https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit) to record a screen (ReplayKit won't work for this) and sometimes I record and save with no problem. Other times I record and when I go to save I get a crash:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriterInput
>   appendSampleBuffer:] Cannot append sample buffer: Must start a session
>   (using -[AVAssetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:) first'

Looking at the StackTrace it's a `__pthread__kill` and it occurs within `thread 83`:

[image]

Specifically within this `DispatchQueue`:

`let audioBufferQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.ahmedbekhit.AudioBufferQueue")`

**How can I prevent this from occurring?**

Here is the code from the file:

```
import AVFoundation
import CoreImage
import UIKit

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class WritAR: NSObject, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    private var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter!
    private var videoInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    private var audioInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
    private var session: AVCaptureSession!

    private var pixelBufferInput: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor!
    private var videoOutputSettings: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>!
    private var audioSettings: [String: Any]?

    let audioBufferQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.ahmedbekhit.AudioBufferQueue")

    private var isRecording: Bool = false

    weak var delegate: RecordARDelegate?
    var videoInputOrientation: ARVideoOrientation = .auto

    init(output: URL, width: Int, height: Int, adjustForSharing: Bool, audioEnabled: Bool, orientaions:[ARInputViewOrientation], queue: DispatchQueue, allowMix: Bool) {
        super.init()
        do {
            assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: output, fileType: AVFileType.mp4)
        } catch {
            // FIXME: handle when failed to allocate AVAssetWriter.
            return
        }
        if audioEnabled {
            if allowMix {
                let audioOptions: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions = [.mixWithOthers , .allowBluetooth, .defaultToSpeaker, .interruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers]
                try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.spokenAudio, options: audioOptions)
                try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            }
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ permitted in
                if permitted {
                    self.prepareAudioDevice(with: queue)
                }
            })
        }

        //HEVC file format only supports A10 Fusion Chip or higher.
        //to support HEVC, make sure to check if the device is iPhone 7 or higher
        videoOutputSettings = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264 as AnyObject,
            AVVideoWidthKey: width as AnyObject,
            AVVideoHeightKey: height as AnyObject
        ]

        let attributes: [String: Bool] = [
            kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String: true,
            kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String: true
        ]
        videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)

        videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        pixelBufferInput = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: nil)

        var angleEnabled: Bool {
            for v in orientaions {
                if UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue == v.rawValue {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }

        var recentAngle: CGFloat = 0
        var rotationAngle: CGFloat = 0
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .landscapeLeft:
            rotationAngle = -90
            recentAngle = -90
        case .landscapeRight:
            rotationAngle = 90
            recentAngle = 90
        case .faceUp, .faceDown, .portraitUpsideDown:
            rotationAngle = recentAngle
        default:
            rotationAngle = 0
            recentAngle = 0
        }

        if !angleEnabled {
            rotationAngle = 0
        }

        var t = CGAffineTransform.identity

        switch videoInputOrientation {
        case .auto:
            t = t.rotated(by: ((rotationAngle*CGFloat.pi) / 180))
        case .alwaysPortrait:
            t = t.rotated(by: 0)
        case .alwaysLandscape:
            if rotationAngle == 90 || rotationAngle == -90 {
                t = t.rotated(by: ((rotationAngle * CGFloat.pi) / 180))
            } else {
                t = t.rotated(by: ((-90 * CGFloat.pi) / 180))
            }
        }

        videoInput.transform = t

        if assetWriter.canAdd(videoInput) {
            assetWriter.add(videoInput)
        } else {
            delegate?.recorder(didFailRecording: assetWriter.error, and: "An error occurred while adding video input.")
            isWritingWithoutError = false
        }
        assetWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = adjustForSharing
    }

    func prepareAudioDevice(with queue: DispatchQueue) {
        let device: AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)!
        var audioDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
        do {
            audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
        } catch {
            audioDeviceInput = nil
        }

        let audioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
        audioDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

        session = AVCaptureSession()
        session.sessionPreset = .medium
        session.usesApplicationAudioSession = true
        session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false

        if session.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput!) {
            session.addInput(audioDeviceInput!)
        }
        if session.canAddOutput(audioDataOutput) {
            session.addOutput(audioDataOutput)
        }


        audioSettings = audioDataOutput.recommendedAudioSettingsForAssetWriter(writingTo: .m4v) as? [String: Any]

        audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
        audioInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

        audioBufferQueue.async {
            self.session.startRunning()
        }

        if assetWriter.canAdd(audioInput) {
            assetWriter.add(audioInput)
        }
    }

    var startingVideoTime: CMTime?
    var isWritingWithoutError: Bool?
    var currentDuration: TimeInterval = 0 // Seconds

    func insert(pixel buffer: CVPixelBuffer, with intervals: CFTimeInterval) {
        let time: CMTime = CMTime(seconds: intervals, preferredTimescale: 1000000)
        insert(pixel: buffer, with: time)
    }

    func insert(pixel buffer: CVPixelBuffer, with time: CMTime) {
        if assetWriter.status == .unknown {
            guard startingVideoTime == nil else {
                isWritingWithoutError = false
                return
            }
            startingVideoTime = time
            if assetWriter.startWriting() {
                assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startingVideoTime!)
                currentDuration = 0
                isRecording = true
                isWritingWithoutError = true
            } else {
                delegate?.recorder(didFailRecording: assetWriter.error, and: "An error occurred while starting the video session.")
                currentDuration = 0
                isRecording = false
                isWritingWithoutError = false
            }
        } else if assetWriter.status == .failed {
            delegate?.recorder(didFailRecording: assetWriter.error, and: "Video session failed while recording.")
            logAR.message("An error occurred while recording the video, status: \(assetWriter.status.rawValue), error: \(assetWriter.error!.localizedDescription)")
            currentDuration = 0
            isRecording = false
            isWritingWithoutError = false
            return
        }

        if videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            append(pixel: buffer, with: time)
            currentDuration = time.seconds - startingVideoTime!.seconds
            isRecording = true
            isWritingWithoutError = true
            delegate?.recorder?(didUpdateRecording: currentDuration)
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        if let input = audioInput {
            audioBufferQueue.async { [weak self] in
                if input.isReadyForMoreMediaData && (self?.isRecording)! {
                    input.append(sampleBuffer)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func pause() {
        isRecording = false
    }

    func end(writing finished: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if let session = session {
            if session.isRunning {
                session.stopRunning()
            }
        }

        if assetWriter.status == .writing {
            assetWriter.finishWriting(completionHandler: finished)
        }
    }

    func cancel() {
        if let session = session {
            if session.isRunning {
                session.stopRunning()
            }
        }
        assetWriter.cancelWriting()
    }
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
private extension WritAR {
    func append(pixel buffer: CVPixelBuffer, with time: CMTime) {
        pixelBufferInput.append(buffer, withPresentationTime: time)
    }
}

//Simple Logging to show logs only while debugging.
class logAR {
    class func message(_ message: String) {
        #if DEBUG
            print("ARVideoKit @ \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970):- \(message)")
        #endif
    }

    class func remove(from path: URL?) {
        if let file = path?.path {
            let manager = FileManager.default
            if manager.fileExists(atPath: file) {
                do{
                    try manager.removeItem(atPath: file)
                    self.message("Successfuly deleted media file from cached after exporting to Camera Roll.")
                } catch let error {
                    self.message("An error occurred while deleting cached media: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the code causing this error:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let input = audioInput {
        audioBufferQueue.async { [weak self] in
            if input.isReadyForMoreMediaData && (self?.isRecording)! {
                input.append(sampleBuffer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before calling `input.append(..)` you should ensure, that your AVAssetWriter session is started. AVAssetWriter seems not to have a property, which returns the state of the session, so you should add a `isSessionStarted` flag to your WritAR class.
Then before calling `input.append(..)` check this flag and (re-)start session if needed.

EDIT: 
Write a helper function to start the session:

```
func startSessionIfNeeded(atSourceTime time: CMTime) {
   if isSessionStarted {
      return
   }
   assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: time)
   isSessionStarted = true
}
```

In your code:

```
func insert(pixel buffer: CVPixelBuffer, with time: CMTime) {
    if assetWriter.status == .unknown {
        guard startingVideoTime == nil else {
            isWritingWithoutError = false
            return
        }
        startingVideoTime = time
        if assetWriter.startWriting() {
            assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startingVideoTime!)
            currentDuration = 0
            isRecording = true
            isWritingWithoutError = true
        } else {
            ...
        }
```

Replace the line `assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: startingVideoTime!)` with the helper function `startSessionIfNeeded(atSourceTime: startingVideoTime)`.

Additionally, change your captureOutput method:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let input = audioInput {
        audioBufferQueue.async { [weak self] in
            self?.startSessionIfNeeded(atSourceTime: self?.startingVideoTime)
            if input.isReadyForMoreMediaData && (self?.isRecording)! {
                input.append(sampleBuffer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still crashed. I c+p the new code in the **captureOutput** method but used optional binding to safely unwrap **self?.startingVideoTime** (it wouldn't take the optional). It keeps giving the same exact crash from that same exact thread, strange

Comment: Than please add some log outputs to your code. especially in "cancel", "end(writing..)" and in the different cases of your "insert" method. Maybe the session is ended by some reason before you try to append the buffer

Comment: Yes there must be something else going on. I'll see if I can print something out. I'll get back to you once I narrow it down. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

The crash may be due to incorrect weak self usage. I fixed the potential crash here - https://github.com/AFathi/ARVideoKit/pull/122/files

Check if it helps.